# Java: online card game library/class/e.g

Tags: java, open-source, class-library, playing-cards

I am looking for java example solution/library/class for online card game. I'm interested in creating a non-profit version of a game called ["Thousand"](http://www.pokertexasomaha.com/thousand.html), with functionality to play human vs human and human vs AI.

I'll appreciate any kind of advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [JPC-API](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpc-api/) which provides general playing card services and rendering.  Beyond that you need to be more specific about what you need.  The problem you describe is a little larget in scope.  Are you looking for help in

- Lobby services (finding other players)
- Gaming network protocol (to communicate moves between players)
- Gaming theory (to write the computer opponent)
- Winning condition detection
- Game UI development

or some other aspect?

Comment: @Jherico - thanks for your input, I'll start from creating UI and gaming network protocol to get going with basic functionality and then I'll try to add mentioned functionalities.